# Are there any legal or licensing issues for shameless cloning proprietary software?

Tags: licensing, cloning

I really want to use a certain tech tool, but the guy wants to charge over $100 for it. It's of sufficient motivation to make me write it myself.

Is there anything wrong with cloning his program, functionality and look, everything and open sourcing it, even though it's a blatant copy? I have no plans to rip his code.

Comment: There may be plenty wrong with it, but it's off-topic here.

Comment: Bigger question should be how long is it going to take you to build it? How many hours is it going to take you to get the same quality product? I'm guessing it will cost you more money to build it yourself

Comment: It'd be a side project, that would make my life easier at work. It's more of a method and a package rather than some new tech. What I'm mainly worried about is getting yelled at and threatened with lawsuits, cuz it's pretty popular.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a lawyer and this is not legal advice, but I think you could mostly get away with it, as long as you truly make everything yourself and don't violate any trademarks.

Lotus v Borland says you can't copyright the functionality of the user interface. But of course, unless you're prepared to fight expensive lawsuits, this may not actually help you.

Also, another big thing to watch out for is patents. If anything in it is patented, you'll have to license it or go without that functionality.